# How do I properly format this JavaScript Array/Object for Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps, object

Having trouble with the Google Maps API in terms of structuring the data coming off of an AJAX request. Here's where I'm at currently:

```
const getMarkerData = function ( googlemap, $hook ) {
const hData = $hook.dataset;
const format = "json";
const dataType = "json";
const markerData = [];
let item = null;

core.api.collection( hData.url, format, dataType ).done(( response ) => {
    const items = response.items;

    if ( response.items ) {
        let i = items.length;

        for ( i; i--; ) {
            item = items[ i ];
            markerData.push({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.location.mapLat, item.location.mapLng),
                title: item.location.addressTitle
            });
        }
    }
    const googleMapMarkers = new google.maps.Marker( markerData );

    googleMapMarkers.setMap( googlemap );
});
};
```

From what I understand, Google Maps wants the data in JSON and not in an array. What I can tweak to get to get it there?

New revised, working code:

```
core.api.collection( hData.url, format, dataType ).done(( response ) => {
    const items = response.items;

    if ( response.items ) {
        let i = items.length;

        for ( i; i--; ) {
            item = items[ i ];

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.location.mapLat, item.location.mapLng),
                title: item.location.addressTitle,
                map: googleMap
            });
            googleMapMarkers.push(marker);
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to treat a single marker as an array of markers.

```
const googleMapMarkers = new google.maps.Marker( markerData );
```

This won't work.

Why not create an instance of `google.maps.Marker` as you are iterating through the items and save push them into an array.  You can also set the map of each in that iteration.

```
var googleMapMarkers = [];

    for ( i; i--; ) {
                item = items[ i ];
                markerData.push({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.location.mapLat, item.location.mapLng),
                    title: item.location.addressTitle
                });

               markerData.setMap(googleMap);
               googleMapMarkers.push(markerData);
            }
```

This is assuming markerData is a valid google map marker.  If it isn't you may have a little more code to construct that object, but it's easily done and plenty examples in the API reference.

Comment: Hey thanks but I'm not sure I understand, I revised the code above to do what I thought you had recommended and it still doesn't seem to work how I'm doing it.

I'm basically iterating through the request and in that process, creating a LatLng instance for the position, and now setting the map as per some of Google's examples. Still not displaying my marker data.

Comment: Nevermind I ended up reworking a bit more to get it right. Thanks again!